# Excel Formula Countifs, Add then Divide to get a %

Tags: excel

Good Morning all,

I have been trying to figure out a formula in excel for 3 days now and can not seem to get it to work I either get a #div/0! or a #VALUE error. Cant find out what im doing wrong.

I need to be able to based of the address in CSH Overview (Column D) sheet count the New Equipment total if it says New or Installed in CSH Test Column W:Z if the address match in both sheets. Once it gets the total then give me a % of new vs installed based of the address. The formula needs to go into CSH Overview Column J: If you can see from my pictures its pulling 1% when it should be pulling 50%

Here are formulas that I have tried:

`=COUNTIFS('CSH Overview'!C:C,'CSH Overview'!D10,'CSH Test'!W:Z,"Installed")`: just to see if i can get a Total installed but this return #Value.

```
=COUNTIF('CSH Test'!C:C,D10) + IF(SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016, "Installed") > 0, COUNTIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016, "Installed") / (SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016, "Installed") + SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016, "New")), 0)

=COUNTIF('CSH Test'!C:C,'CSH Overview'!D10) + COUNTIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"Installed") / (SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"Installed") + SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"New"))
```

`=COUNTIF('CSH Test'!C:C,'CSH Overview'!D10) + SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"Installed") + SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"New")`: This one worked to get me the total of new vs installed per the address but cant get it to do the other part if what I want.

```
=COUNTIF('CSH Test'!C:C,'CSH Overview'!D10) + SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"Installed") + SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"New") - SUMIF('CSH Test'!W1:Z1016,"Installed")*100/100

=IFERROR(SUM(COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!W:W,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!X:X,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Y:Y,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Z:Z,"Installed")) /
SUM(COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!W:W,"New") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!X:X,"New") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Y:Y,"New") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Z:Z,"New")*100)/100,"")
```

This is the formula thats pulling the 1% currently

[image: CSH Overview]

[image: CSH TEST]

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work

```
 =IFERROR(SUM(COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!W:W,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!X:X,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Y:Y,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Z:Z,"Installed")) /
SUM(COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!W:W,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!X:X,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Y:Y,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Z:Z,"Installed") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!W:W,"New") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!X:X,"New") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Y:Y,"New") +
COUNTIFS('CSH Test'!C:C,[@Address],'CSH Test'!Z:Z,"New")) *100/100,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to modify the value of a good result in order to modify the way it is shown? Using "Format Cells" (context menu of a cell) you can alter the way the content of a cell is represented.

In my case, I have put the value "0.5" in both cells, but in the second cell I have modified the cell formatting as indicated in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you understand what I am trying to do. The value I'm getting is either wrong because the percentage is not correct from what I need or I'm getting an error as the value. That 1% value should be 50 percent as you can see the picture there is 10 new and 10 installed so the new vs installed should be 50% not 1%